# Tizen IDE does not seem to recognize Javascript

Tags: javascript, ide, tizen

The Tizen IDE doesn't find the usages or declarations of any Javascript variable -- it just tells me that that element cannot be found. I see there's a "Javascript Search" option in one of the menu bars, but it likewise can't find anything. Does anyone know how I can get the IDE to recognize Javascript so that it can find the references/usages of a variable? 
I'm running currently on a Windows 7 machine but hope to have a Mac soon.

Comment: You haven't really asked a question. If you have feedback regarding the Tizen IDE you're probably better off posting it at the Tizen developers' forums.

Comment: OK I edited it for clarification and to narrow the scope. Wasn't sure if all the issues were related or not so I figured I'd just put them all up.